# Odoo 13 : How to set one2many field to empty when creating record from xml data?

Tags: xml, odoo-13

I want to create a new salary structure, but when I create a new one, there are 3 salary rules  automatically linked to my new strucutre, here are them : 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
And I did it like this but doesn't work :

```
    <record id="structure_base_malagasy" model="hr.payroll.structure">
        <field name="name">Structure Salariale Malagasy</field>
        <field name="type_id" ref="hr_payroll.structure_type_employee"/>
        <field name="regular_pay" eval="True"/>
        <field name="rule_ids" eval="[(5, 0, 0)]"/>
        <field name="country_id" eval="False"/>
    </record>
```

with rule_ids eval="[(5, 0, 0)]", I'm getting these errors :

> odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "ERREUR:  une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne « struct_id »
> DÉTAIL : La ligne en échec contient (17, Basic Salary, BASIC, null, 1, 1.0, 1, t, t, none, contract.wage,
> # Available variables:
> ..., null, null, code, null, null, result = payslip.paid_amount, null, null, null, 1, 2020-06-28 19:05:41.55551, 1, 2020-06-28 19:44:19.025471)

Can you help me?

Comment: Is there an other code using `hr.salary.rule`?

Comment: Not in my custom, may be in native addons

Comment: I can't reproduce the same issue so try to add a function to set `rule_ids` empty as they did in [l10n_be](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/054d4bc6bc219bcc6b0a64265e8d7e9c7423dbc8/addons/l10n_be/demo/l10n_be_demo.xml#L18)

Comment: @Kenly, one of my idea to get rid of this. Will use that if there is no other solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I think its like that:

```
<field name="rule_ids" eval="[]"/>
```

And then add your rules with your structure id.

I have not converted my rules to v13 yet. But I think its how it is done.

Comment: Let me try that one, and will give feed back to you,

Comment: doesn't work because structu_id of hr.salary.rule is required and if I place rules before structure, i got error "can't find external id". Your answer works on Odoo v10, but not in v13.